For how many "young" people in the Vampirates series do we know where they're from?
The Vampirates series is set in the 2500s, at a time when "the oceans have risen", the implication being that the world is now so dominated by water that most people live on the sea, hence most of the series being set on pirate or vampirate ships. In this era, how many countries or national identities still exist?
Some of the (vampirical) characters are so ancient that they predate the rising of the oceans, such as Sidorio who comes from ancient Cilicia and Lorcan who comes from 19th-century Ireland. What about the "young" (i.e. normal human age) characters: the Tempest twins, the Wrathe brothers, the Li dynasty, Bart, Cate, Jez, etc.? How many of them have known origin countries, indicating that those countries or identities still exist in the 25th-26th centuries?
I'm interested in textual evidence from the books themselves (preferred above extratextual sources saying Crescent Moon Bay is in Australia), indicating the place of origin of any of the <100-year-old characters (whether or not they get converted to vampires during the course of the series).

Extratextual? The very first page of the first book says that Crescent Moon Bay is on the east coast of Australia; "Crescent Moon Bay, east coast of Australia. The year 2505."

@Showsni Ugh, SFF.SE and its love of author interviews ... post that as a second answer over there and I'll switch the acceptance :-) This question here is different though: even if we know CMB is in what's now geographically Australia, does the cultural concept of "being Australian" still exist in 2505? (Spoiler: yes, because I remember Grace mentions being Australian in-universe somewhere in book 3 when talking with whatisface the treacherous dhampir, but this question is also broader than just that.)

Yes, I've been flicking through my copies looking for specifics, but there don't seem to be many; Connor recognises some vases as being "Chinese" in the first book, but that doesn't really indicate if China still exists.
